# jQuery, does element has style

Tags: jquery, css

Using jQuery, how can I say 'Does a child of #parent have the stlye="width"'.

I know the beginning...

```
jQuery('#parent').children();
```

But I dont know how to write has style 'width'.

EDIT

In the html the div says style="width=xxx". I want to find the first occurrence of that width and add a margin: 0 auto; to that div. Its for centering videos.

Some of the divs that say style="width" are 3 levels nested from the top. That still should work with `.children()` right?

For some reason, i cant get any of the below codes to work...

Comment: Do you mean *has the `width` style specified on the element itself* or *has a `width` style applied from anywhere, including stylesheets*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an ["attribute contains" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

> **Description:** Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring.

```
jQuery('#parent [style*="width:"]')
```

That will give you the children of `#parent` that have the string `width:` in their `style` attribute.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vpdGa/1/

If you need to worry about `border-width` and similar CSS properties, then you could add your [regular expression selector](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/):

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
```

And then search thusly:

```
jQuery('#parent :regex(style,(^|\\s)width:)')
```

Don't forget the extra backslash to get past the string literal's backslash interpretation.

And an example of this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vpdGa/4/

Comment: But that would match `min-width`, `max-width`, `outline-width` and `border-*-width`, as @Sjoerd says in his comment.

Comment: This works for me, but how can i add a class to the child who has the width?

Comment: @Frédéric: Good point, I added an update that patches a regex selector into jQuery so that we can deal with the troublesome properties.

Comment: @cnotethegr8: You'd add a class the same way you'd add a class to any other jQuery object: `$(...).addClass(class_name)`.

Comment: @mu, it still won't work if the `style` attribute begins with `width`. +1 for the regex selector plugin, however :)

Comment: @mu is too short: There are several different video players, all with there own ID and Class names. I need to be able to define any class that has the width style...

Comment: @Frédéric: But fixing my regex brain damage takes care of the `/^width/` issue (and fixes my "not enough backslashes" problem too). Did I miss anything else?

Comment: @cnotethegr8: You're looking for anything that has a width specified anywhere at all? Even from a CSS class or assigned from JavaScript?

Comment: @me is too short: Basically i different video embeddings. I dont have access to the code of them. Im wrapping a class around the video code. I want to use javascript to find the class i wrapper around the video, and than look for the first child that has in the html a width defined. Than i want to add to the element .css('margin','0 auto'); This will center the video. I cant add this to the parent element since the width is not yet defined. Thanks

Comment: @mu, well, your regex still matches `awidth` ;) Maybe use `:regex(style,(^|\s)width:)`?

Comment: @Frédéric: Actually, you need `(^|\\s)` to get the `\` past the string literal, you need escape your escapes, escapes all the way down :)

Comment: @notethegr8: I think you're going to need to include some real HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: @mu, you're absolutely right, I tested it with a `/`-delimited native regex before commenting, and *that* doesn't require backslash escaping. Silly me :)

Comment: @mu: I'm using a wordpress shortcode to get videos. A shortcode looks like this `[video player-url-here]`, but it outputs code like `<div id="id"><div class="class"><video></div></div>`. Because of this i dont have access to edit the code. so im wrapping a class around the shortcode. `<div class="center">[video]</div>` I want the javascript to see class="center" and look inside for an element saying `style="width:(any number)"` and add to that element `margin: 0 auto`. The outcome of this is to get the video player to be centered. Does this make sense?

Comment: @notethegr8: Then you probably want `$('.center :regex(style,(^|\\s)width:)').css('margin', '0 auto')` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
 var width = $(element).css('width')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery' attr which gets you if it has widht or not

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

do a length check on the result

it should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `prop()` method, as seen here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

```
 function checkStyleAttr(elSelector,attr){
    return new RegExp('[^-]'+attr+'[ ]*:').test($(elSelector).attr('style'));
}
```

Comment: This will return true for `width` if the element has `min-width` or `border-width` set.